# Matrix Difference Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$x_{k+2} - (2b) x_{k+1}+x_k=0$$
Here $x_k$ is a $2 \times 1$ column matrix sequence ($ k \ge 1$), $b$ is a constant.

I know the form of answer, 
$$x_k=A \cos(k\cos^{-1}(b))+B\sin(k\cos^{-1}(b))$$
Here $A,B$ are $2 \times 1$ constant matrices. 
However I cannot derive the answer.

Usually, in similar case, I use a form of recursion formula
$(x_{k+2}-a \cdot x_{k+1})=c(x_{k+1}-a \cdot x_k)$
But I'm not accustomed to matrix recurrence relation and this form doesn't work well in this case... And I think in this way, I cannot find the answer in given form.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why don't you solve the equation for each row of the matrix independently?